# What is analog of devextreme dxItem element in react?

Tags: reactjs, layout, devexpress, devextreme

As I understand that the layout in DevExtreme composed by Box elements and "dxItem"s inside of Box elements.
React has Box class but no "dxItem" analog (or I not found it).
How I can make layout in DevExtreme with React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. As dxItem you can use any html element like the div with attribute like

```
<div data-options='dxItem: {baseSize:"auto", ratio:1}'>...</div>
```

But now I have another problem. All devextreme elements like Button not functional. They like to freezed inside of Box...